# Create another database from changelog: automatic data type conversion issue

Tags: database-migration, liquibase

I get the changelog from PostgreSQL database with the command:

```
liquibase \
   --driver=org.postgresql.Driver \
   --classpath="C:\db_drivers\postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc3.jar" \
   --changeLogFile="./postgresql_changelog.xml" \
   --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" \
   --username=schema_name_here \
   --password=*** \ 
   --logLevel=debug \ 
   --defaultSchemaName=sep \
   generateChangeLog
```

Here is a fragment of postgresql_changelog.xml:

```
...
<createTable tableName="table1">
    <column name="total_pk" type="INT8">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="form_fk" type="INT8">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="territory_fk" type="INT8">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="parameter_fk" type="INT8">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="enterprise_fk" type="INT8">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="total_g" type="INT8">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="total_data" type="date">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="total_value" type="numeric(*, 2)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="variant_fk" type="INT8">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="period_id" type="INT8">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="total_q" type="INT8"/>
    <column name="total_m" type="INT8"/>
    <column name="increase" type="INT8"/>
    <column name="period_index" type="INT8"/>
    <column name="data_input" type="TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE"/>
    <column name="document_unid" type="VARCHAR(64)"/>
    <column name="value_comment" type="VARCHAR(512)"/>
    <column name="olap_year" type="SMALLINT"/>
    <column name="olap_month" type="SMALLINT"/>
    <column name="olap_week" type="SMALLINT"/>
    <column name="olap_day_of_month" type="SMALLINT"/>
    <column name="olap_quarter" type="VARCHAR(4)"/>
    <column name="olap_quarter_desc" type="VARCHAR(17)"/>
    <column name="olap_month_name" type="VARCHAR(8)"/>
    <column name="ediz_id" type="INT8">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="olap_month_code" type="VARCHAR(10)"/>
    <column name="olap_month_caption" type="VARCHAR(64)"/>
</createTable>
...
```

Now I want to create the same objects and the same relationships in another database (Oracle):

```
liquibase \
   --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
   --classpath="C:\db_drivers\ojdbc14.jar" \
   --changeLogFile="./postgresql_changelog.xml" \
   --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip_here:orabeta" \
   --username=*** \
   --password=*** \
   update
```

But it does not work: [ORA-00902](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm)

It is possible to get changelog from one database and update another database in different RDBMS server from this changelog? I need to get automatic data type conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is - **yes**. But it is necessary to manually correct the data types in the generated file. Data types are not converted automatically.

See Also:

- [Generate XML/ SQL output with data types of target database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530887/generate-xml-sql-output-with-data-types-of-target-database/25570497#25570497)
- [Liquibase, Column tag](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html)